# Creating new columns in a dataGridView from the values in a dictionary

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a program which reads fields from an XML file into a dictionary. I would like to name and create columns in a dataGridView from the values in the dictionary. The problem is, I'm not going to know until run time what the values in the dictionary are going to be, and in what order. Is there a way to do this programatically, and also to specify which type of column they are going to be (like a combobox, textbox, etc)?

```
 custXML=
        doc.Descendants("DT100")
           .ToDictionary(d => (int)d.Element("import_seq"),
                         d => (string)d.Element("display_name"));
```

Where custXML is a Dictionary with import_seq as key and display_name as value. Here's what I tried adding to my datagridview (there are fixed 64 columns, some of which might be empty):

```
DataGridViewColumn[] foo = new DataGridViewColumn[64];
for (int i = 0; i < 63; i++)
  foo[i] = new DataGridViewColumn();

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> item in custXML)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 63; i++)
    foo[i].HeaderText = item.Value.ToString();
}

for (int i = 0; i < 63; i++)
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(foo[i]);
```

However, when I run that, the names of the columns all say "Source Code"

Comment: can you provide a sample of your design time code so that we can see the structure of your XML ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> item in custXML)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 63; i++)
                foo[i].HeaderText = item.Value.ToString();
        }
```

you repeatedly change all of the column headers to the same string. So they all end up with the name of the last item in you XML.  Instead of looping over all of the DataGridViewColumns, for each new key value pair you need to set the title of the appropriate DataGridViewColumn.

I will leave the implementation as an exercise for you :)

**Edit to answer the comment:**

The foreach iterates the dictionary, but the inner loop applies the current dictionary item to all of the columns.  So in the end, all of the columns get the item value of the last dictionary entry.  If I understand what you are trying to do, you probably want to replce the inner loop with

```
if (item.Key >= 0  && item.Key <= 63)
    foo[item.Key].HeaderText = item.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: I don't know, I thought item.Value.ToString() was iterating through the dictionary, hence it wasn't stuck on the last item. Oh well.